# Ajax tab not executing script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, tabs

I am using JQuery UI tabs to load content through Ajax. I have two tabs that should load html content and execute a script to hide or show some elements in the loaded content. I was running into an issue where script that is returned from Ajaxified content not executing when second tab is clicked. Script is executing when the first tab clicked.

I have code snippet here to reproduce the problem. Can this be fixed?

Here is the HTML page has tab listing

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>tabs demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="tabContent.html"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="tabContent.html"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$("#tabs").tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tab content html file tabContent.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#HideShowMe").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#HideShowMe").hide();

    $('#Cancel').click(function () {
        $('#HideShowMe').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#HideShowMe').hide();
    });

    $('#Show').click(function () {
        $('#HideShowMe').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#HideShowMe').show();
    });

});
</script>

<h2>Ajxified Content</h2>
<div id="ActionHideShow">
<input type="button" id="Cancel" name="command" value="Cancel" />
<input type="button" id="Show" name="Show" value="Show" />
</div>

<div id="HideShowMe">
<p>Hello there I should hide at any cost</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a case of duplicate IDs! ID attributes should be unique in any given document.

From [Answer from JQuery UI forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-tab-not-executing-script)